# Why mousemove event cripples number input in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In Chrome v.25 I use this code to avoid text cursor while dragging HTML element:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) { e.returnValue = false; });
```

Every `<input type="number"/>` is crippled  (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uP7TH/1))

I already managed to avoid this by setting the false returnValue only while dragging. But what exactly happens here? Is it a bug or some feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with CSS, if I understand what you mean correctly...

```
.no-select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Just add that to the elements that you don't want to be selectable.

This does look like rather a string issue, as I wouldn't call pressing up on a number input a mousemove event, but in any case, the issue exists. The CSS may be a more elegant solution.

Check the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uP7TH/3/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I just want the input to behave correctly. See the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uP7TH/2/)

Comment: Remove your JavaScript too :), it'll still be stopping it, see the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: I see. Kinda useful. I use the javascript for another purposes, I just narrowed the problem. Thanks anyway.